# make install saying CUDADIR environment variable not set, when it is

Tags: makefile, magma

I'm currently trying to install [MAGMA](http://icl.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/index.html), however trying to run "sudo make install" gives me the error:

```
$ sudo make install prefix=/usr/local/magma
make.check-cuda:7: *** Set $CUDADIR, preferably in your environment, e.g., 
run "export CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda" in ~/.bashrc, or "setenv CUDADIR 
/usr/local/cuda" in ~/.cshrc.  Stop.
```

I know for sure that CUDADIR is set, and it's set in ~/.bash_profile, so I'm not sure why it's failing. Is there any reason why it might not being finding it? It seemed to work fine when I ran "make".

```
$ set | grep CUDADIR
CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be both set *and* exported.  By looking at the output of `set` you're just seeing variables which are set in the shell... the shell will only send exported variables to programs (like `make`) that it invokes.  You didn't show us how the variable is set in `~/.bashrc` but I assume it's something like this:

```
CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda
```

Change that to:

```
export CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda
```

If you want to see what variables are exported the simplest thing to do is use `env`, not `set`, like this:

```
$ env | grep CUDADIR
```

Comment: No, it was in my ~/.bash_profile correctly, as "export CUDADIR...". In the end I actually ended up getting it to work by setting the variable in the make.inc file. I still don't know why it didn't pick it up otherwise though.

Comment: If you run the `env` command I suggested did you see it there?  If so then all I can suggest is that somewhere in some makefile, `CUDADIR` is set to empty as a make variable.  That seems odd if they expect you to set it in your environment.